# Exception safety and make_unique

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr, exception-safety

Just to clarify, using `make_unique` only adds exception safety when you have multiple allocations in an expression, not just one, correct? For example

```
void f(T*);

f(new T);
```

is perfectly exception safe (as far as allocations and stuff), while

```
void f(T*, T*);

f(new T, new T);
```

is not, correct?

Comment: Your question appears to contradict itself. First you assert that multiple-allocations are exception-safe, then you show an example where this is ostensibly the opposite of what happens.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit no, I asserted that multiple allocations are not exception safe. I said "make_unique only adds exception safety when you have multiple allocations in an expression" which means it adds nothing for only one allocation.

Comment: your question lacks any use of `make_unique` or `unique_ptr` in your examples because?

Comment: @Yakk because it doesn't need it

Comment: `multiple allocations in an expression` but each of those allocations via `new T` _is_ a separate expression, so you have the opposite: one allocation per each of multiple expressions. That the function call is _itself_ an expression containing the other 2 doesn't change that. But aside from the wording, you were on the right track. By my reading, the rule, as formulated by Sutter, is to perform each allocation within its own **statement** or **sequence** them by returning from a separate function call, thereby avoiding weird ordering & leaks: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/056.htm (oldie-but-goodie)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Not only when you have multiple allocations, but whenever you can throw at different places. Consider this:

```
f(make_unique<T>(), function_that_can_throw());
```

Versus:

```
f(unique_ptr<T>(new T), function_that_can_throw());
```

In the second case, the compiler is allowed to call (in order):

- `new T`
- `function_that_can_throw()`
- `unique_ptr<T>(...)`

Obviously if `function_that_can_throw` actually throws then you leak. `make_unique` prevents this case.

And of course, a second allocation (as in your question) is just a special case of `function_that_can_throw()`.

As a general rule of thumb, just use `make_unique` so that your code is consistent. It is always correct (read: exception-safe) when you need a `unique_ptr`, and it doesn't have any impact on performance, so there is no reason not to use it (while actually *not* using it introduces a lot of gotchas).

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. Sorry to ruin your 2^13 rep.

Comment: A little late, but make_unique can itself throw according to cppreference: make_unique "may throw std::bad_alloc or any exception thrown by the constructor of T. If an exception is thrown, this function has no effect." So how is that exception safe? And what happens to a unique_ptr object (named or temp) that is initialized with make_unique, but make_unique throws?

Comment: Exception safety is not (just) about "no exceptions" but rather about "guaranteeing the right behaviour when you get an exception". The `make_unique` documentation is clear: no effect if there is an exception, this is a strong guarantee (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_safety). And the `unique_ptr` is not yet constructed so, again, no effect; the exception is simply propagated.

Answer (score 25):

As of C++17, the exception safety issue is fixed by a rewording of [[expr.call]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.call#5)

> The initialization of a parameter, including every associated value computation and side effect, is indeterminately sequenced with respect to that of any other parameter.

Here *indeterminately sequenced* means that one is sequenced before another, but it is not specified which.

```
f(unique_ptr<T>(new T), function_that_can_throw());
```

Can have only two possible order of execution

1. `new T` `unique_ptr<T>::unique_ptr` `function_that_can_throw`
2. `function_that_can_throw` `new T` `unique_ptr<T>::unique_ptr`

Which means it is now exception safe.

Answer (score 8):

I'd think you'd be better off comparing things actually using `std::unique_ptr<T>`:

```
void f(std::unique_ptr<T>);

f(std::unique_ptr<T>(new T));
f(std::make_unique<T>());
```

Neither of these calls can leak if there is an exception being thrown. However

```
void f(std::unique_ptr<T>, std::unique_ptr<T>);

g(std::unique_ptr<T>(new T), std::unique_ptr<T>(new T));
g(std::make_unique<T>(), std::make_unique<T>());
```

In this case, the version using `std::unique_ptr<T>` explicitly can leak if an exception is thrown (because the compiler might start evaluating the `new`-expressions before constructing either of the temporaries).