# Exceptionsafety of make_unique: Why is f(new T) exception safe

Tags: c++, exception, c++14, exception-safety

I have been reading [GOTW102](http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_102/), and wonder, why `make_unique` is more exception safe than the other cases, or in detail why `f(new T(...))` is more exception safe than `f(new T1(...), new T2(...))`.

The `make_unique` implementation from the blog reads:

```
template<typename T, typename ...Args>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique( Args&& ...args )
{
    return std::unique_ptr<T>( new T( std::forward<Args>(args)... ) );
}
```

Now I wonder if `f(new T(...))` is in general exception safe (leak free), or if it is just exception safe in the case of `make_unique` because of the added knowledge that the constructor of `std::unique_ptr` does not throw? (Since if it would the freshly constructed `T` would be leaked anyways according to my understanding.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19472550/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason is that in a function call or similar, the arguments do not induce sequence points (are not "sequenced before"). For example:

```
do_work(unique_ptr<A>(new A), unique_ptr<B>(new B));
```

The compiler is allowed to generate code that looks like:

1. `new A`
2. `new B` // might throw!
3. Construct `unique_ptr<A>`
4. Construct `unique_ptr<B>`
5. Call `do_work`

If `new B` throws, then you've leaked the `A`, because no `unique_ptr` was ever constructed.

Putting the `unique_ptr` construction into its own function eliminates this problem, because compilers aren't allowed to execute function bodies concurrently (so the "new" and "construct `unique_ptr` steps need to be done together).

---

That is, given:

```
do_work(make_unique<A>(), make_unique<B>())
```

The compiler must generate code that looks like:

1. Call `make_unique<A>`
2. Call `make_unique<B>`
3. Call `do_work`

or

1. Call `make_unique<B>`
2. Call `make_unique<A>`
3. Call `do_work`

making the leak where there are new'd objects floating around without owning `unique_ptr`s not possible.

Comment: I understand most of this, my question is more focused on `make_unique`. It is defined as function that does `unique_ptr<A>(new A)`. Where do I get the gurantee from that `unique_ptr<A>` does not throw after `new A` finished (I don't see a bit of code that could throw => it won't throw). But if the constructor of `unique_ptr` could throw, it would not be exception safe (aka A would be leaked), right?

Comment: @ted: You get that guarantee because C++11 20.7.1.2 [unique.ptr.single]/1: `// 20.7.1.2.1, constructors [...] explicit unique_ptr(pointer p) noexcept;` <-- declared `noexcept`

Comment: Incidentally, `shared_ptr`'s constructor from a raw pointer *can* throw (it has to allocate the control block), but it's guaranteed to delete the pointer in that case, so nothing is leaked.

Comment: @T.C.: were could I find the reference on this?

Comment: @BillyONeal: I could only find N3337, which does not have `20.7.1.2.1`. SO what is up with what `T.C.` posted: is there a case conceivable were what he said  happens? (While pondering this, since that was the only case I could think of for `unique_ptr` failing, I briefly thought that this case does not exist, which was wrong).

Comment: @ted I was talking about `shared_ptr`, not `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @ted: Look for [unique.ptr.single] -- the section numbers change in various releases of the standard. That said I'm not sure unique_ptr is in 3337; you may need a copy of the standard at least as recent as C++11.

Comment: @ted: Try N3376, the first working paper after C++11