# shared_ptr<> to an array custom deleter (with make_shared)

Tags: c++, arrays, shared-ptr

Is it possible to use *make_shared* and a custom deleter for an array that a shared_ptr<> points to (below is the way I tried doing it via the constructor, but I have no idea how that would work via using make_shared)?

```
int n = 5;
shared_ptr<int> a(new int[n], default_delete<int[]>());
```

What I would like to make it look like is something similar to this, but with allocating memory for an int array and also having a custom deleter. Is that possible?

```
int n = 5;
shared_ptr<int> a;
a = make_shared<int>();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [shared\_ptr to an array : should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061979/shared-ptr-to-an-array-should-it-be-used)

Comment: @Sneftel While the question there is similar, the one you linked does not comply with make_shared, which is the issue I got here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to specify a custom deleter as of right now with `std::make_shared`, you could however, make a wrapper around `make_shared` if you want

([a little less efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895648/difference-in-make-shared-and-normal-shared-ptr-in-c), but ¯\_(ツ)_/¯)

```
template <typename Type, typename Deleter, typename... Args>
auto make_shared_deleter(Deleter&& deleter, Args&&... args) {
    auto u_ptr = std::make_unique<Type>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    auto with_deleter = std::shared_ptr<Type>{
        u_ptr.release(), std::forward<Deleter>(deleter)};
    return with_deleter;
}
```

And then use it like so

```
int main() {
    auto ptr = make_shared_deleter<int>(std::default_delete<int>(), 1);
    cout << *ptr << endl;
}
```

---

If you just want to use a `shared_ptr` and have it point to an array, see [shared_ptr to an array : should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061979/shared-ptr-to-an-array-should-it-be-used) for more

Comment: Ah, I see. That helps a bit. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: I mean, you don't *really* need `with_deleter` :)

Comment: But a big part of using `std::make_shared` is the reduction in allocations, this doesn't address that

Comment: @PasserBy A big part of `std::make_shared` is also ensuring exception safety (as with `std::make_unique`).  I already mentioned in my answer that the above is less efficient than `std::make_shared` because of the repeated allocation.

Comment: Exception safety issue is [resolved in C++17](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44932594/4832499). And for the efficiency part, it's not immediately apparent that what the problem is, maybe link to a post about that?