# Is it true that unique_ptr which points to an array will automatically free dynamic memory after calling release()?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

As far as I know, calling `std::unique_ptr<T,Deleter>::release` only transfers ownerships, won't free the dynamic memory.

From *C++ Primer 5th*:

```
p2.release(); // WRONG: p2 won't free the memory and we've lost the pointer
auto p = p2.release(); // ok, but we must remember to delete(p)
```

But after a few pages it writes:

> The library provides a version of `unique_ptr` that can manage arrays allocated by
>   new. To use a `unique_ptr` to manage a dynamic array, we must include a pair of
>   empty brackets after the object type:

```
// up points to an array of ten uninitialized ints
unique_ptr<int[]> up(new int[10]);
up.release();   // automatically uses delete[] to destroy its pointer
```

> The brackets in the type specifier (`<int[]>`) say that up points not to
>   an int but to an array of ints. Because up points to an array, when up
>   destroys the pointer it manages, it will automatically use `delete[]`.

---

So is it true that `std::unique_ptr<T,Deleter>::releas` treats dynamically allocated array differently, which is freeing the allocated memory automatically after calling `release()`? If it's true, then it also indicates that one can't transfer ownership of an dynamic array. I couldn't find any authoritative references on the Web so far.

Comment: I think it's not true. I can't find it documented on cppreference and I can't reproduce: [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FvhgwlKmbwKg9QkL). Destructor is not called. Memory is leaked.

Comment: release -> reset typo

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I looked a little in this, and I'm guessing this was just a mistake on the author's part. [cppreference.com makes no reference to any array specialization for `release`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/release). Just to make sure, I went ahead and checked the source code for libc++ (LLVM's implementation of the standard library). [This is the implementation for `std::unique_ptr<T[], Deleter>::release`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/memory#L2843). As you can see, it does not call `delete[]`. My guess is the author meant to write `up.reset();`, as [this does free the memory](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset).

Answer (score 8):

> ```
> // up points to an array of ten uninitialized ints
> unique_ptr<int[]> up(new int[10]);
> up.release();   // automatically uses delete[] to destroy its pointer
> ```

This is incorrect. `up.release()` is not calling `delete[]` for the array it manages. It is simply releasing ownership of the array and returning a pointer to it. It is, therefore, the responsibility of the coder to call `delete[]`.

I think you are getting mixed up with [`std::unique_ptr<T, Deleter>::reset()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset) which does free the allocated memory.

Demo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Test
{
public:
    Test() { std::cout << "Test()" << std::endl; }
    ~Test() { std::cout << "~Test()" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Test[]> up(new Test[3]);
    auto ptr = up.release();

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Test()
Test()
Test()
```

The destructor is not called. So we have a memory leak! The only way to avoid this is to call `delete[] ptr;` after `auto ptr = up.release();`

**Note**: from C++14 onward you can write:

```
std::unique_ptr<CTest[]> up = std::make_unique<CTest[]>(3);
```

This is [better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472550/exception-safety-and-make-unique) than explicitly new-ing because it will not leak if an exception is thrown.